# Why is the mass delete of reports function not removing reports?

Tags: reporting, bulk-delete, recycle-bin

Per the Summer 14 release instructions I've found in Stack Exchange I am trying to delete a large quantity of reports using the mass delete function.

I open setup then 'Data management" then 'mass delete records' then 'mass delete reports'.  I select "last run" in the first column, "less than" in the second column, and type "LAST 12 MONTHS" in the third column.  I click Search and a list is populated along with this note:

> "Note: You have reached the maximum number (250) of deletable Reports at one time. If you would like to delete more Reports, first delete the ones below and then perform another mass delete."

I select all then click 'Delete'.  The screen flashes as though it's working then the same list appears.  Even if I leave the screen and repopulate it's the same list.  If I look in Recycle Bin all the reports seem to be there so I clear the Recycle Bin but going through the same steps comes up with the same list.  Any thoughts on what is wrong with this process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your reports are used in any `Dashboards`, they will fail to delete using this bulk action, but also not provide any error messages. You need to find the `Dashboards` containing these `Reports` and delete them, or remove the `Reports` from them.